# How to check whether a folder exists or not in gcp cloud storage out of 1 million folders

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bigdata, binary-tree, bucket

For example I have structure like this.

```
bucketname/checked/folder1/some files
bucketname/checked/folder2/some files
bucketname/checked/folder3/some files
bucketname/checked/folder4/some files
bucketname/checked/folder5/some files
bucketname/checked/folder6/some files
bucketname/checked/folder7/some files
bucketname/checked/folder8/some files
bucketname/checked/folder9/some files
bucketname/checked/folder10/some files
bucketname/checked/folder11/some files
......
......

bucketname/checked/folder-1million/some files
```

Now,

**1. If I have to check whether folder99999 exists or not. So,what would be the best way to check it (we have information of folder name - folder99999) ?**

**2. If we simply check path that exists or not, and if not then it means, folder don't exists. would it work fine If we have millions of folders?**

**3. Which data structure gcp uses to retrieve the folder data ?**

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not have folders. The namespace is flat. You cannot check if a folder exists, only objects. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders

Comment: thanks. Can you comment on one more thing, if there are millions of objects, would it be feasible to look for that object without much time complexity? I mean would it be scalable?

Comment: Study documents such as https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#naming-convention How you name objects with a bucket can affect scalability in negative ways. There is the mathematics behind object name caching and name collisions. Google search for white papers. AWS has similar issues. Papers for either will help you understand.

Answer (score 4):

The true answer is this one provided by John: folder doesn't exist. All the files are stored at the root directory (bucket level) and the file name is the full path. By human convention, the `/` is the folder separator and the console display fake folders.

If you haven't files in a "folder", the "folder" doesn't exist, it's not interpreted/deduced from the name fully qualified path. The folder is not a Cloud Storage resource

It's also for that reason that you search only by path prefix

---

However, it depends what you want to check. If you exactly know which folder you want to check and validate, and if there is at least one file in it, you can directly [list the files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) with the folder path as prefix.

Comment: thanks. Can you comment on one more thing, if there are millions of objects, would it be feasible to look for that object without much time complexity? I mean would it be scalable?

Comment: Again, if it's a direct access, and you expect to answer the question: Does it exist? Yes or No; yes, it's feasible with millions/billions of object. Now, if you look for a file pattern (and you don't know the prefix/folder path), you have to scan millions of object to check if it exists, and, this time, it takes long, long, long time.

Comment: `gsutil ls -d` is available for inspecting the subdirectory itself, as found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls).

Comment: @FeiYao: Directory DOES NOT EXIST!